# How to manipulate the value of a row based on the condition and the row above?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df and I want to group it by `links` and sort it by `time`. Then, everytime `type == 'vehicle leaves traffic'` the cell in the column `count` should add +1 of the cell value in the preceding row. If `type == 'vehicle enters traffic'` it should deduct 1 from the preceding row.

For clarification, not the preceding row's value should be changed, but the value of the row should be changed based on the preceding value.

This is my approach, but all I get is 0, 1 and 2. I'm expecting much higher values for some links.

```
parking_min <- cars %>% 
  group_by(link)%>% 
  dplyr::mutate(count = if_else(type == 'vehicle leaves traffic', lag(count, n=1,order_by=time)+1,lag(count))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(count = if_else(type == 'vehicle enters traffic',lag(count, n=1, order_by=time)-1,lag(count)))
```

This is my data:

```
structure(list(time = c("23707.0", "31209.0", "31210.0", "36230.0", 
"36231.0", "38925.0", "39583.0", "40198.0", "40818.0", "41974.0", 
"42895.0", "43099.0", "43683.0", "44645.0", "45730.0", "46785.0", 
"48846.0", "48905.0", "52790.0", "53829.0", "55021.0", "58240.0", 
"58635.0", "59682.0", "59683.0", "63740.0", "63776.0", "68607.0", 
"24607.0", "25218.0", "26442.0", "28004.0", "29884.0", "37750.0", 
"42623.0", "43965.0", "49426.0", "54925.0", "56688.0", "56689.0", 
"57738.0", "61900.0", "64221.0", "67065.0", "69404.0", "77454.0", 
"83588.0", "89601.0", "27452.0", "27743.0", "33598.0", "36297.0", 
"60604.0", "62940.0", "63184.0", "63250.0", "20911.0", "27013.0", 
"29815.0", "49550.0", "53991.0", "55620.0", "61200.0", "67672.0", 
"78558.0", "79245.0", "27006.0", "29085.0", "31411.0", "36747.0", 
"36877.0", "38434.0", "38807.0", "44607.0", "58068.0", "58800.0", 
"65236.0", "65431.0", "69013.0", "69072.0", "25609.0", "29520.0", 
"46559.0", "66916.0", "74904.0", "78407.0", "20445.0", "23938.0", 
"24017.0", "24281.0", "25283.0", "25873.0", "27137.0", "27342.0", 
"28790.0", "28910.0", "29241.0", "29345.0", "29465.0", "29525.0", 
"29909.0", "30719.0", "31092.0", "31356.0", "31786.0", "32829.0", 
"33966.0", "34175.0", "34545.0", "34888.0", "34977.0", "35775.0", 
"35950.0", "38409.0", "38636.0", "39259.0", "39527.0", "40256.0", 
"40385.0", "40564.0", "40691.0", "40774.0", "42271.0", "42469.0", 
"42895.0", "43103.0", "43223.0", "43599.0", "44476.0", "44903.0", 
"44904.0", "45774.0", "45834.0", "45915.0", "46230.0", "46287.0", 
"46626.0", "47215.0", "48784.0", "50266.0", "50361.0", "50763.0", 
"52685.0", "52793.0", "54688.0", "55105.0", "56310.0", "57885.0", 
"58093.0", "58153.0", "59223.0", "60460.0", "60597.0", "60676.0", 
"61307.0", "61457.0", "61974.0", "62141.0", "62165.0", "62347.0", 
"62591.0", "64175.0", "64280.0", "65555.0", "65808.0", "66038.0", 
"66391.0", "66723.0", "66735.0", "66736.0", "66933.0", "67502.0", 
"67989.0", "68322.0", "68785.0", "69318.0", "70450.0", "70634.0", 
"71069.0", "71741.0", "72121.0", "72292.0", "73236.0", "73775.0", 
"74280.0", "80298.0", "80458.0", "80976.0", "81035.0", "84189.0", 
"84302.0", "85602.0", "23296.0", "34106.0", "34107.0", "55975.0", 
"55976.0", "57434.0", "60561.0", "70091.0", "26085.0", "26163.0", 
"26654.0", "27473.0", "28303.0", "29212.0", "29380.0", "29581.0", 
"29707.0", "30802.0", "31052.0", "33174.0", "34020.0", "36031.0", 
"36392.0", "38037.0", "40717.0", "42099.0", "43154.0", "44413.0", 
"44414.0", "44730.0", "44770.0", "46863.0", "46876.0", "48318.0", 
"48435.0", "48493.0", "48700.0", "51736.0", "51747.0", "51748.0", 
"52221.0", "52302.0", "52599.0", "52921.0", "53104.0", "53230.0", 
"53443.0", "54494.0", "55053.0", "56555.0", "56717.0", "58381.0", 
"62245.0", "62554.0", "63050.0", "63050.0", "63447.0", "63507.0", 
"64054.0", "65090.0", "65090.0", "65217.0", "65218.0", "66571.0", 
"66945.0", "67715.0", "68169.0", "68921.0", "68955.0", "69081.0", 
"70123.0", "70263.0", "71413.0", "74609.0", "75930.0", "75931.0", 
"76676.0", "77855.0", "88490.0", "92653.0", "23458.0", "23770.0", 
"29531.0", "29532.0", "32320.0", "32735.0", "47644.0", "50879.0", 
"50971.0", "51427.0", "55554.0", "57334.0", "57971.0", "59064.0", 
"66852.0", "68689.0", "69206.0", "72502.0", "84592.0", "84593.0", 
"90207.0", "90208.0", "34426.0", "74433.0", "32354.0", "64161.0", 
"67914.0", "21864.0"), type = c("vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle enters traffic", "vehicle leaves traffic", 
"vehicle enters traffic"), vehicle_id = c(1267069L, 810534L, 
810534L, 51825L, 51825L, 1326473L, 1199672L, 1111105L, 1111105L, 
532654L, 532654L, 1267069L, 1199672L, 1398907L, 1398907L, 1239391L, 
1239391L, 1326473L, 46491L, 46491L, 1179923L, 434774L, 434774L, 
4205L, 4205L, 1269433L, 1179923L, 1269433L, 1454119L, 1412246L, 
1310775L, 1278645L, 1533113L, 1430553L, 1430553L, 1533113L, 1533113L, 
492533L, 1430553L, 1430553L, 492533L, 1278645L, 1454119L, 1533113L, 
1278645L, 1310775L, 1412246L, 1278645L, 1161080L, 1290940L, 558745L, 
628509L, 628509L, 1161080L, 558745L, 1290940L, 403850L, 774916L, 
1530598L, 403850L, 1397256L, 3874L, 774916L, 1530598L, 1397256L, 
3874L, 193835L, 1043798L, 1043798L, 1881121L, 193835L, 1221124L, 
1881121L, 1221124L, 12799L, 12799L, 526654L, 2066556L, 526654L, 
2066556L, 485689L, 486288L, 488147L, 486288L, 485689L, 488147L, 
1925302L, 2821L, 1919641L, 2147547L, 1785664L, 1394390L, 1869032L, 
1812540L, 1531804L, 1814856L, 1531804L, 2149105L, 1747951L, 1908352L, 
1854886L, 1888344L, 1926462L, 1925659L, 1887358L, 1926462L, 1863281L, 
1094609L, 1888344L, 1925659L, 1222534L, 2148165L, 1863281L, 2148165L, 
1814856L, 1885007L, 1094609L, 1887358L, 1925302L, 1925659L, 1908352L, 
1919641L, 1885007L, 1898426L, 1222534L, 2095866L, 1812540L, 1528492L, 
2149105L, 1799420L, 1799420L, 1898426L, 2095866L, 1905635L, 1859644L, 
1528492L, 1187619L, 1794294L, 1908352L, 1187619L, 2149105L, 1901830L, 
1859644L, 1885718L, 1925659L, 4806833L, 1901830L, 1794294L, 4806833L, 
2821L, 1905635L, 1785664L, 1887788L, 2149105L, 1885718L, 1912658L, 
1394390L, 1457624L, 1869032L, 2147547L, 1908352L, 2064554L, 1457624L, 
1902958L, 1888247L, 1888247L, 1670344L, 1898186L, 1378838L, 1378838L, 
1840443L, 1747951L, 1887788L, 5259385L, 1215125L, 2064554L, 1912658L, 
1887316L, 42794L, 1860654L, 1902958L, 1854886L, 5259385L, 1887316L, 
1670344L, 42794L, 1921295L, 1921295L, 1860654L, 1840443L, 1898186L, 
1215125L, 80518L, 1131784L, 1131784L, 1060825L, 1060825L, 80518L, 
1345214L, 1345214L, 29916L, 29916L, 534393L, 519878L, 525457L, 
523658L, 529842L, 526134L, 534394L, 529842L, 523658L, 529554L, 
526214L, 29916L, 526214L, 529554L, 479492L, 530841L, 1856482L, 
514510L, 514510L, 693877L, 479492L, 29916L, 1270690L, 1856482L, 
526134L, 693877L, 790707L, 520491L, 568524L, 568524L, 520491L, 
1455918L, 513349L, 29916L, 534585L, 790707L, 513349L, 532803L, 
530834L, 1270690L, 1455918L, 526134L, 1309724L, 1309724L, 519877L, 
519877L, 533986L, 476491L, 525457L, 519877L, 519877L, 398460L, 
398460L, 530834L, 534393L, 519878L, 1145089L, 476491L, 537161L, 
530841L, 533986L, 29916L, 526134L, 534585L, 513028L, 513028L, 
1145089L, 537161L, 532803L, 534394L, 273572L, 273572L, 861460L, 
861460L, 216294L, 216294L, 230683L, 1365760L, 230683L, 310759L, 
1521962L, 1521962L, 310759L, 1365760L, 1535243L, 1247561L, 1535243L, 
1247561L, 230658L, 230658L, 1277451L, 1277451L, 1428056L, 1428056L, 
1140384L, 46083L, 1140384L, 1343106L), link = c(90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 389L, 
389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 
389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 
451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 
480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 
578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 662L, 
662L, 662L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 774L, 774L, 
774L, 774L, 774L, 774L, 774L, 774L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 
927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 
927L, 987L, 987L, 988L, 988L, 988L, 1277L), count = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(18798L, 64777L, 64783L, 90025L, 90030L, 
102868L, 105834L, 108690L, 111727L, 118283L, 124349L, 125700L, 
129642L, 135888L, 142577L, 148772L, 161264L, 161590L, 182778L, 
187946L, 193712L, 211483L, 213953L, 220930L, 220932L, 252098L, 
252362L, 284709L, 24007L, 27759L, 35618L, 45777L, 57274L, 97498L, 
122488L, 131443L, 164666L, 193274L, 202313L, 202319L, 208399L, 
237611L, 255705L, 275635L, 288938L, 316125L, 328641L, 334960L, 
42227L, 44153L, 77374L, 90336L, 227678L, 245970L, 247907L, 248400L, 
6850L, 39423L, 56892L, 165451L, 188728L, 196734L, 232209L, 279294L, 
318618L, 320203L, 39374L, 52544L, 65925L, 92485L, 93136L, 100641L, 
102349L, 135630L, 210380L, 215004L, 263248L, 264622L, 286884L, 
287214L, 30294L, 55175L, 147465L, 274669L, 309732L, 318235L, 
5646L, 20075L, 20529L, 22040L, 28176L, 31997L, 40252L, 41570L, 
50757L, 51465L, 53497L, 54091L, 54830L, 55211L, 57389L, 61972L, 
64148L, 65630L, 67926L, 73590L, 79237L, 80209L, 81961L, 83619L, 
84034L, 87938L, 88723L, 100516L, 101524L, 104339L, 105567L, 108951L, 
109580L, 110436L, 111056L, 111525L, 120134L, 121493L, 124350L, 
125721L, 126499L, 129085L, 134769L, 137553L, 137562L, 142843L, 
143218L, 143719L, 145566L, 145897L, 147872L, 151431L, 160891L, 
169439L, 169951L, 172179L, 182269L, 182796L, 192084L, 194128L, 
200320L, 209292L, 210580L, 210957L, 217800L, 226596L, 227622L, 
228226L, 233050L, 234180L, 238184L, 239554L, 239746L, 241169L, 
243114L, 255350L, 256150L, 265478L, 267279L, 268878L, 271245L, 
273444L, 273513L, 273515L, 274788L, 278257L, 281213L, 283103L, 
285741L, 288499L, 293964L, 294807L, 296677L, 299364L, 300811L, 
301489L, 304733L, 306468L, 307953L, 322532L, 322917L, 324007L, 
324134L, 329621L, 329788L, 331476L, 16560L, 79874L, 79878L, 198570L, 
198576L, 206594L, 227352L, 292291L, 33304L, 33809L, 37031L, 42365L, 
47741L, 53329L, 54310L, 55545L, 56255L, 62460L, 63930L, 75298L, 
79478L, 89112L, 90807L, 98845L, 111205L, 119068L, 126025L, 134327L, 
134337L, 136437L, 136711L, 149242L, 149320L, 158130L, 158789L, 
159131L, 160368L, 177328L, 177392L, 177394L, 179845L, 180260L, 
181812L, 183400L, 184268L, 184922L, 185978L, 191177L, 193860L, 
201573L, 202492L, 212365L, 240333L, 242817L, 246833L, 246834L, 
249842L, 250280L, 254468L, 262163L, 262164L, 263107L, 263117L, 
272463L, 274866L, 279549L, 282270L, 286442L, 286606L, 287265L, 
292441L, 293100L, 298081L, 308952L, 312468L, 312471L, 314309L, 
317028L, 334227L, 336208L, 17419L, 19144L, 55246L, 55251L, 70799L, 
73085L, 154041L, 172793L, 173296L, 175721L, 196355L, 206048L, 
209794L, 216742L, 274263L, 285199L, 287908L, 302276L, 330230L, 
330233L, 335274L, 335275L, 81402L, 308426L, 71000L, 255248L, 
280759L, 10158L), class = "data.frame")
```

Possible output:

```
          time                   type vehicle_id link count
18798  23707.0 vehicle enters traffic    1267069   90     0 #start point
64777  31209.0 vehicle leaves traffic     810534   90     1 #+1
64783  31210.0 vehicle enters traffic     810534   90     0 #-1
90025  36230.0 vehicle leaves traffic      51825   90     1
90030  36231.0 vehicle enters traffic      51825   90     0
102868 38925.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1326473   90     1
105834 39583.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1199672   90     2 #here as well 1+1 =2
108690 40198.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1111105   90     3 #2+1 =3
111727 40818.0 vehicle enters traffic    1111105   90     2 #3-1 =2
118283 41974.0 vehicle leaves traffic     532654   90     3
124349 42895.0 vehicle enters traffic     532654   90     2
125700 43099.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1267069   90     3
129642 43683.0 vehicle enters traffic    1199672   90     2
135888 44645.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1398907   90     3
142577 45730.0 vehicle enters traffic    1398907   90     2
148772 46785.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1239391   90     3
161264 48846.0 vehicle enters traffic    1239391   90     2
161590 48905.0 vehicle enters traffic    1326473   90     1
182778 52790.0 vehicle leaves traffic      46491   90     2
```

Eventually I want to find the maximum count for each link. But that can be done in another step and does not need to be part of the solution, perhaps it helps to clarify the question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a **minimal** reproducible example (and maybe the expected output).

Comment: @Georgery, the minimal reproducible example I have provided, I belive. Ill try to describe the desired output, its a bit tricky by hand.

Comment: @Georgery a solution example has been added :)

Comment: what I meant was that it would be nicer to provide a sample dataset that contains maybe 10 rows and not 300. ;)

Comment: @Georgery aha, I'm sorry, I always worry to give too little^^ Ill try then to consider better the minimal number of necessary rows:) thanks for the hint and your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(link) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(
    adder = case_when(
      type == "vehicle leaves traffic" ~ 1,
      type == "vehicle enters traffic" ~ -1,
      TRUE ~ 0),
    count = count + cumsum(adder)
    ) %>% 
  select(-adder)
```

which gives

```
      time                   type vehicle_id link count
1  23707.0 vehicle enters traffic    1267069   90     0
2  31209.0 vehicle leaves traffic     810534   90     1
3  31210.0 vehicle enters traffic     810534   90     0
4  36230.0 vehicle leaves traffic      51825   90     1
5  36231.0 vehicle enters traffic      51825   90     0
6  38925.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1326473   90     1
7  39583.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1199672   90     2
8  40198.0 vehicle leaves traffic    1111105   90     3
9  40818.0 vehicle enters traffic    1111105   90     2
10 41974.0 vehicle leaves traffic     532654   90     3
```

Comment: You might wanna add some sorting by time?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
df %>%
    arrange(link, time) %>%
    group_by(link) %>%
    mutate(vehicles_entered_traffic = cumsum(type == "vehicle enters traffic")
           , vehicles_left_traffic = cumsum(type == "vehicle leaves traffic")
           , count = count[1] + vehicles_left_traffic - vehicles_entered_traffic)
```